# Как лучше делать фильтр (get или post)?

Tags: php, html

Каким методом HTTP лучше передавать обращение к форме? 
Например, на сайте имеется форма, использующая различные виды инпутов - radio, select, и т.д.

Comment: Если выбирать между `GET` и `POST`, лучше `POST`, он и как глагол по смыслу больше подходит и точно не будет кэшироваться в отличии от `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно метод GET применяется в том случае, если на результаты выполнения обработчика формы требуется ссылаться с других Web-страниц и эти результаты постоянны. POST используется, если не требуется ссылаться на результаты работы формы и результаты могут отличаться (в зависимости от того кто выполняет, времени, операции и т.п.).